# Layout doesn't change after modifying constants

Tags: ios6, autolayout

I have a `UIView` on my `UIViewController`. I set width and height using Editor -> Pin -> Width/Height. Also i created `IBOutlet` of these constraints to change widht and height programatically. I worte code

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewWidth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeight;
```

in .m file

```
self.viewWidth.constant = 480;
self.viewHeight.constant = 644;
```

but still its not changing the width and height of view. Am i missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the constants, you need to invoke `-layoutIfNeeded` or `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution  to update constants of constraints programmatically without IBOutlet.

[Hide autolayout UIView : How to get existing NSLayoutConstraint to update this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384927/hide-autolayout-uiview-how-to-get-existing-nslayoutconstraint-to-update-this-o)