# Hide autolayout UIView : How to get existing NSLayoutConstraint to update this one

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout, show-hide, nslayoutconstraint

I know how to modify a existing constraint. But I would to know if someone has found a solution to get a constraint without save this one as a property.

Current solution to set Constraint height:

**1) save NSLayoutConstraint in a variable:**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                     constant:20];
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

**2) Set the constant of the Constraint saved to "0.0" ( to hide this view)**

```
[heightConstraint setConstant:200];
```

---

**I'm looking for a solution like this:**

```
 [myView setConstraint:@"0." forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just built this Category (https://github.com/damienromito/UIView-UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints) that update constrains when you want:

```
//you can use tools to hide/show a uiview
[myView1 hideByHeight:YES];
```

[image]

**Or just do it** to hide an UIView with autolayout:

```
//Hide View 
[myView1 setConstraintConstant:0 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight];
```

Comment: Where is the category implementation? It's not in github.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I push the category now. https://github.com/damienromito/UIView-UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints.git

Answer (score 6):

UIView has a method that returns all constraints affecting its layout in one of the dimensions:

```
NSArray *constraints = 
[someView constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Then you can just find the one you're interested in.

Comment: this method return an empty NSArray. To get all constraints "NSArray *constraints = [self.view constraints]" works very good.

Comment: I built a category, look at the EDIT of my Question.

Comment: @DamienRomito Great. Consider posting it as a separate answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The documentation for `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:` specifically states "This method should only be used for debugging constraint-based layout. No application should ship with calls to this method as part of its operation."

Comment: @DamienRomito `constraints` does not provide you with all constraints that effect a view. It only provides you with the constraints that a particular view hosts. They may not effect it at all (only its children).

Comment: This method should only be used for debugging constraint-based layout. No application should ship with calls to this method as part of its operation.